# Elemento não se expande totalmente

Tags: html5, css3

Alguem pode me responder pq essa lista do meio não se expande todo como o resto? Da uma olhada

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.formacao {
    background-color: #141414;
    color: #fff;
}

.faculdades {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 1rem;
}

.faculdades-cursos {
    background-color: #000;
    padding: 20px;
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.formacao .subtitulo {
    color: #000000;
}

.formacao-texto {
    color: #a3a3a3;
}

.formacao-texto strong{
    color: #fff;
}

.faculdades-tipo {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.faculdades-curso {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
```

```html
<section class="formacao">
        <div class="formacao-info experiencia">
            <h1 class="subtitulo">formação</h1>
            <div class="formacao-info-div">
                <p class="formacao-texto experiencia-texto">Minha mais recente experiência acadêmica foi o <strong>mestrado</strong>  que fiz no exterior em <strong>UX Design</strong>. Além disso me mantenho sempre atualizado com cursos intensivos online.</p>
                <ul class="faculdades">
                    <li class="faculdades-cursos">
                        <span class="faculdades-tipo">BACHAREL</span>
                        <h3 class="faculdades-curso">Administração de Empresas</h3>
                        <span class="faculdades-empresa">UFRRJ</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="faculdades-cursos">
                        <span class="faculdades-tipo">TECNÓLOGO</span>
                        <h3 class="faculdades-curso">Design Digital</h3>
                        <span class="faculdades-empresa">Infnet</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="faculdades-cursos">
                        <span class="faculdades-tipo">MESTRE</span>
                        <h3 class="faculdades-curso">User Experience Design</h3>
                        <span class="faculdades-empresa">UCLL</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score -2):

Bem, pra oque eu acho que tu quer fazer, seria bom aplicar um width na div dessa lista, no caso, pra quando ela estiver na tela maximizada , minimizada e por ai vai.